# Javascript calculate average after groupement

Tags: javascript, average, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working with [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) and [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) in order to make a dashboard.

**What I have ?**

Let's consider these documents :

```
{
    "Mkt_Al": "AZA",
    "Orig" : "PTH",
    "Dest" : "GMP",
    "Qsi"  :  2

}

{
    "Mkt_Al": "AZA", // here the same triplet
    "Orig" : "PTH",
    "Dest" : "GMP",
    "Qsi"  :  3

}

{
    "Mkt_Al": "AZA", // here the same triplet
    "Orig" : "PTH",
    "Dest" : "GMP",
    "Qsi"  :  4

}
```

**What I want ?**

I should group documents by the triplet ( `Mkt_Al` , `Orig` , `Dest` ) then I should calculate the average of the `Qsi` in this group.

```
    {
        "Mkt_Al"  : "AZA",
        "Orig"    : "PTH",
        "Dest"    : "GMP",
        "Qsi"     :  2,
        "Avg_Qsi" : 3


    }

    {
        "Mkt_Al"  : "AZA", // here the same triplet
        "Orig"    : "PTH",
        "Dest"    : "GMP",
        "Qsi"     :  3,
        "Avg_Qsi" : 3
    }

    {
        "Mkt_Al"  : "AZA", // here the same triplet
        "Orig"    : "PTH",
        "Dest"    : "GMP",
        "Qsi"     :  4,
        "Avg_Qsi" : 3

    }
```

**How to do that ?**

I have a `dataSet`, and with [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) `datatable` I tried to draw a data table with a column which will countain this average:

```
 {
                label: 'Average Qsi in this route', 
                format: function (d) 
   {
                var total=0,avg=d.Qsi;
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
      {
  if (dataSet[i].Mkt_Al == d.Mkt_Al
   && dataSet[i].Orig == d.Orig  
   && dataSet[i].Dest == d.Dest)
  { total = total+1; avg=(avg+dataSet[i].Qsi/total); }

       }
                   return avg;
    }
 }
```

Please how can I achieve the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very near from the result :

```
 {
                label: 'Average Qsi in this route', 
                format: function (d) 
   {
                var total=0,qsi=0; // our counters
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) 
      {
  if (dataSet[i].Mkt_Al == d.Mkt_Al
   && dataSet[i].Orig == d.Orig  
   && dataSet[i].Dest == d.Dest)
  { total++ ; qsi =dataSet[i].Qsi+qsi; } // here total calculate the number of flights with these condition and qsi calculate the sum of documents's qsi which verify these results

       }

                   return (qsi/total).toFixed(3); 
    }
 }
```